# Kadison Schwarz Inequality proof via 2 positivity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

While reading Holevo's book on Quantum Information Theory, there was an exercise question.

Let $\Phi$ be a 2-positive linear operator map (between $\mathcal{L}(H)$ to $\mathcal{L}(H)$, $H$ being a Hilbert space). That is:
$$\Phi\otimes I_2 \geq 0$$
where $I_2$ is the identity map for $2\times 2$ matrices. Then show that for any operator $X\in \mathcal{L}(H)$,
$$\Phi(X^*)\Phi(X)\leq \|\Phi(I)\|\Phi(X^*X)$$

The hint was to exploit 2-positivity. I then checked some of the answers on the site, but I observed that either those were special cases of above or they gave some alternate proof. I'm not very comfortable manipulating tensors, but this is what I got so far.

Proof: 
Let $T$ be defined as
$$\tag{a}T=\begin{bmatrix}
I && X \\
0 && 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Then $T^*T\geq 0$ and 
$$T^*T=\begin{bmatrix}
I && X \\
X^* && X^*X
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now 
$$\tag{b}(\Phi \otimes I_2)(T^*T)=\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi(I) && \Phi(X) \\
\Phi(X^*) && \Phi(X^*X)
\end{bmatrix} \geq 0 $$

Now for any vector $U$ in the tensor space we have that $\langle U^*(\Phi \otimes I_2)( T^*T)U\rangle \ge 0$. Now if $\Phi(I) = \|\Phi(I)\|I = \alpha I$, then pick 
$$U=\begin{bmatrix}-\Phi(X) \\ \alpha I \end{bmatrix}$$
Substitute in the inner product above to get the result.

Now I have a few doubts about this proof:

$(a)$ Is $T$ as defined above an element in the tensor space? I have trouble visualizing it.

$(b)$ Is step (b) valid. All i've done is apply Phi to every element in the matrix.

$(c)$ Is $\Phi(I)=\alpha I$ as I've mentioned above? I only have a proof if this is true. The proofs I've seen earlier assume $\Phi$ is unital, so this is not an issue there.

In short, I have trouble visualizing $\Phi \otimes I_2$. I'd appreciate it if someone can clear the aforementioned doubts.

**Update:** I think I should view $T$ as 
$$T=I\otimes \begin{bmatrix}1 && 0\\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix} + X\otimes \begin{bmatrix}0 && 1\\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update is correct. What you did in step $(b)$ is precisely to apply that $\Phi$ is $2$-positive.

To finish your proof, what you need to notice is that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\|\Phi(I)\|\,I && \Phi(X) \\
\Phi(X^*) && \Phi(X^*X)
\end{bmatrix} \geq\begin{bmatrix}
\Phi(I) && \Phi(X) \\
\Phi(X^*) && \Phi(X^*X)
\end{bmatrix} \geq 0.
$$
Then you can finish the proof with your $U$, or you use the result that if a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}I&A\\ A^*&B\end{bmatrix}$ is positive, then $A^*A\leq B$.

Comment: So I was able to do the proof save for the $\|\Phi(I)\|I\geq \Phi(I)$ part. Could you offer some advice on that?

Comment: It's the inequality $A\leq \|A\|\,I$, that holds for any positive element in any C$^*$-algebra.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of this inequality. Let me try proving it. Suffice it to say, that answers everything :)

Comment: $0\leq \langle x|A|x\rangle \leq \|Ax\|\|x\| \leq \|A\|\|x\|^2$. But $\|x\|^2=\langle x|x\rangle$. So $\|A\|\|x\|^2 = \langle x|\|A\|I\ |x \rangle$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Yes, that works if you already know that you can represent your C$^*$-algebra as operators on a Hilbert space. The inequality can be obtained in a more abstract setting from the Gelfand transform.